# ASP.net Web Page Database error

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, sdf

Hi here is my cshtml code:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("SiteDB");
    var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM Favorite";
    var data = db.Query(sqlQ);
}

    <div id="movieslist">
    <ol>
        @foreach(var row in data)
        {
            <li><a href= "#">@row.Name, @row.Category, @row.ReleaseYear
            </a></li>
        }
    </ol>
    </div>
```

sqlDB.sdf is local. I get this error when I run a site:

Keyword not supported: 'file access retry timeout'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'file access retry timeout'.

Source File: c:\Users\Saheed\Documents\My Web Sites\My Empty Site\dataMovies.cshtml    Line: 4

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`file access retry timeout` in your connection string (in Web.config) is invalid.

Comment: I have no Web.config, am using webMatrix and my db (siteDB.sdf) is local. Am not using a connection string instead I connect thus : var db = Database.Open("SiteDB");